# Nodejs, Express How to pass variable to route and use it in external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, routes

I am working on a web app using MongoDB Express NodeJS stack and in one of the routes I am getting array from database and then passing it to route.
Code:

```
app.get("/badges/new", function(req, res) {
    Colour.find({}, function(err, foundCoulours) {
        if(err){
            console.log("error: "+ err);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            res.render("badges/new",{foundCoulours:foundCoulours})
        }
    });
});
```

All done easily but here is a bit that I am stuck at the moment: I want to use jQuery to add elements onto the page depending on the result that came from server. I can do it using script tag and in-line JS on the ejs file without any problems but what I would like to do is to use external JavaScript file so my ejs wouldn't look as massive just with `<script src="public/foo.js"></script>`. 
Question: Is there a way to pass **foundCoulours** to `"public/foo.js"` file after it was passed to route? Or maybe I can pass it straight to `"public/foo.js"` file from the request route.

Comment: dude, really Mango or Mongo!

Comment: Sorry my bad. Mongodb with mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sequentially load the scripts. As below:

**Jade**

```
body
script(type='text/javascript').
      var foundCoulours= #{foundCoulours}
script(type='text/javascript', src="foo.js")
```

**EJS**

```
<script>
 var foundCoulours = <%= foundCoulours>
</script>
<script src="public/foo.js"></script>
```

**Explained:**
As we are loading foundCoulours variable in global scope, it is directly accessible in foo.js, as it is loaded after the variable is initialized.

Comment: Thanks will try it out tomorrow! Now that I think about it, it makes sense!

Comment: We load jQuery library before using it in our scripts file, as it exposes jQuery to global scope. Same goes with angularJS and rest libraries.